# Redirecting everyone who doesn't have a specific user agent in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've seen people redirect iPhone users by using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-iPhone-site/ 
RewriteRule .* /my-iPhone-site/ [R]
```

But how could I make a webpage only accessible with a specific user agent? Instead of blacklisting iPhones, I would like to whitelist them, for example.

Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MrWhite's answer didn't work for some reason, but this was how I figured it out.

```
 SetEnvIf User-Agent .*iPhone* iPhone

 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from env=iPhone
```

This will take all non iPhone users to 403.

Comment: "`.*iPhone*`" - Should be `.*iPhone.*`, or simply `iPhone` (since regex is greedy by default). If the solution in my answer didn't work then maybe the directives are in the wrong place(?) - they should be near the top of the `.htaccess` file (the order of the mod_rewrite directives is important). Although I think your solution is preferable (+1) - but note that `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` are Apache 2.2 directives. If you are on Apache 2.4 then these should be converted to use `Require`.

Answer (score 1):

To only allow requests to `/my-iPhone-site/...` from user-agents that contain `iPhone` then you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` (near the top):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !iPhone
RewriteRule ^my-iPhone-site/ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) any user that tries to access `/my-iPhone-site/...` that does not contain `iPhone` in the user-agent string.

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex. So, in this example, it is successful when the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` server variable does *not* contain the string "iPhone".

If you wanted to *redirect* such users instead then change the `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^my-iPhone-site/ /non-iPhone-site/ [R,L]
```

NB: You should use the `L` flag when redirecting, otherwise processing continues through your file.